# Validate angular2 HTML and CSS with Webpack

Tags: html, css, validation, angular, webpack

I have an angular2 project that uses webpack to process all the typescript, html, and css.

I would like to validate my HTML and CSS/SCSS every time it's rebuilt, but I don't see any webpack loaders to do this. Not sure if I'm just searching for the wrong things, but searches like `webpack validate html template angular2` aren't returning anything related.

The only way I have to validate the HTML right now is to load the relevant part of the page, copy the rendered source to a string and put it in the [w3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/nu/).

Any suggestions for webpack loaders to validate HTML and CSS/SCSS?

Comment: You should check angular2-webpack-starter they are using loaders for each thing check their webpack config

Comment: @BabarBilal They just use the normal `sass-loader`, `css-loader`, and `style-loader` for CSS, and don't have any special loaders for HTML. They don't do any validation for valid HTML or CSS.

Comment: @mtfurlan: Hi, did you find any solution?

Comment: @PraveshKhatri I have not, sorry.